# Perform the web3.eth.sendRawTransaction() for multiple recipient addresses inside a loop using Nodejs

Tags: node.js, ethereum, web3js

I am trying to create a program that sends ETH from an account address to many. I created the below code however, it only sends an ETH to the first value of the function's ***_to*** parameter.

So every time I reload the page, I expect the function to perform the ***sendRawTransaction()*** to all accounts defined inside ***_to*** parameter, but it does not.

I am new to ethereum guys, any suggestion/help would be really awesome!

```
function multipleSend(_from, _to, _key) {
    // var x = "";

    var key = new Buffer(_key, 'hex');
    var amount = 1;
    for(var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        nonce = balance(_from);
        var rawTx = {
            nonce: web3.toHex(nonce),
            gasPrice: web3.toHex(10),
            gasLimit: web3.toHex(21000),
            to: _to[i],
            value: web3.toHex(amount * 1000000000),
            data: "",
            chainId: i+=1
        }
        var transaction = new tx(rawTx);
        transaction.sign(key);
        var serializedTx = transaction.serialize().toString('hex');
        web3.eth.sendRawTransaction('0x'+serializedTx, function(err, hash){
            if(!err){stat = hash;}
        });
    }
    return stat;
}

multipleSend(accounts[0].toString(),[accounts[1].toString(),accounts[2].toString(),accounts[3].toString()], '1e3f65b1dbfe697255b8d287fbcba2b999ec8520af1ae67c21e3ae825889f557');
```

Answer (score 0):

This line looks very wrong:

```
chainId: i+=1
```

Each transaction uses a different chain ID, which can't be what you want. Also, `i` is incremented twice in each iteration of the loop, so you're certainly not going to send three transactions.

One other suspicious bit of code:

```
nonce = balance(_from);
```

What does `balance` do? That's also a very weird name for a function that determines the account's `nonce`. In writing a loop like this, I would recommend getting the correct `nonce` once and then incrementing it with each transaction rather than determining it again. Otherwise you're probably not taking into account the transaction(s) you just sent when determining the nonce.

Comment: Yea I'm sorry I think I shouldve included the entire code ahaha. Anyway, balance(_from) returns the current nonce of the sender. I should probably rename that to avoid confusion ;D

for chainId, I'm not totally sure what it does or serve. But since it is an ID I thought maybe I could use each instance of i, and not iterate it once more... but if you can share to clear what that chainID is for, thatd be awesome.

Comment: for the loop's condition, i modified it to _to.length...

finally, I actually achieved my goal. the function performs for each address identified within _to. I am using requestjs to call the function and it did work. although I stumbled into another problem where the request() method does not terminate.

I'll post the entire code later, em only using my phone rn.

Comment: `chainID` identifies for which blockchain the transaction is valid. See https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-155.md for the correct values for various chains.

Comment: I also just noticed that you're sending an extremely low gas price: 10 wei, while a standard mainnet gas price right now is 3 gwei. (This may not cause you problems yet if you're testing on a local network, but it will probably cause problems when you try to use this in production.)